# angular2 router avoid url encoding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am fairly new to Angular 2 and do not know the correct terms to search for in order to get what i need.

I am using Angular 2 RC5 and the RouterModule in my app. When I pass params for a route to navigate to, Angular 2 Router automatically URL encodes it. Now although thats a good thing but is there a way to prevent it for certain params?

For example, I want to add comma separated values in the URL:
`http://localhost:4200/appcomponent/?data=abc1,abc2,abc3`

What angular 2 makes it:
`http://localhost:4200/appcomponent/;data=abc1%2Cabc2%2Cabc3` (which looks rather messy)

Any suggestions how to make it more readable in URL?

Thanks!

Comment: can you specify exact router library that you are using and provide your code? thanks!

Comment: I am using the default router library from Angular 2 (@angular/router: 3.0.0-rc.1)

`let paramsObject = {data: 'abc1,abc2,abc3'};
this.router.navigate(['/appcomponent', paramsObject]);`

Comment: check out my answer below for similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding/41995695#41995695

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 disable url encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding)

Answer (score 14):

You could navigate by Url instead:

```
 router.navigateByUrl('/parent/11/(simple//right:user/victor)');
```