# Angular2 : incorrect encoding of colon in the URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, url-encoding

I'm trying to build an app with two router-outlets so that one of them would be a left menu. I have a link in this left menu that loads a component in the main outlet, but if I click on it, the left-menu component disappears, so I added `(left-menu:leftmenu)` to it.
This is the template for the left menu (`left-menu.component.html`):

```
<div class="leftmenu">
  <a routerLink="/form(left-menu:left-menu)">Go to the form!</a>
</div>
```

And this is the routes array that I pass to `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`:

```
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LeftMenuComponent,
    outlet: 'left-menu',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'leftmenu',
    component: LeftMenuComponent,
    outlet: 'left-menu',
  },
  {
    path: 'form',
    component: ProjectFormComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo: ''
  }];
```

But what I see is that the rendered URL in the link is not `/form(left-menu:left-menu)` but `/form(left-menu%3Aleft-menu)`, so the link doesn't work. On the other hand, if I write the right URL (with the colon) in the browser it works properly (that is, the `ProjectFormComponent` is loaded and the `LeftMenuComponent` remains in the left outlet).

Anyone knows why this happens?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does it work if you put square brackets around the routerlink, and surround the url in single quotes, eg `[routerLink]="'form(left-menu:left-menu)'"`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work either :(

Comment: I don't want to take credit for this solution by providing it as an answer, but this works.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding