# angular 4 routing params error

Tags: angular, routes, angular4-router

My angular 4 application implements routing, one of my path is `detail/:code`.
But my code isn't a simply number, is a partial string path like this `/user/4`
It works well when I navigate appending this code to my principal endpoint but when I land into this detail page if I look into my url bar I found this path

> http://localhost:4200/dashboard/user-detail/%2Fusers%2F2

It use escape %2 for my '/',
I can't change my code into a number, is it possible to figure out the correct url?

Comment: Provide please a plunker example, it seems that the url in the routerLink attribute is broken

Comment: @MikeKovetsky At the moment I have a selectable table, when I click on some records I do this:` this.router.navigate`(['/dashboard/user-detail', this.code]);` path in user-detail is 'user-detail/:code'

Comment: Your each escape `/` is getting encoded to `%2F` since it's part of the url. See this question on how to handle that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding

Comment: Also, just a note, if you pass `/user/4` to route `/dashboard/user-detail`, it's going to look like `/dashboard/user-detail//user/4`

Comment: Yes, ok so the solutions for the symbol like / is to implements a custom serializer