# Angular4+ decode route parameters

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I have such URL in my app:

```
http://example.com/page/payments;offerId=5
```

After exploring the page (going back and forth, reloading page) sometimes this url gets encoded to

```
http://example.com/page/payments;offerId%3D5
```

and breaks my page because I use route.snapshot.params... somewhere in the code. After more reloads it gets even more complicated (while still breaking the app):

```
http://example.com/page/payments;offerId%25253D5%253D%3D=.
```

Sometimes this situation doesn't happen, sometimes it fixes itself, but most often it stays as described and breaks the page.

I could write custom parser that cleans and decodes url params to proper object or try to get param's values directly from url cutting the garbage off, but that would not be very practical, and would involve a lot of guesswork.

Are there any methods or workarounds to fix that issue?

EDIT: I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding) and I will try to implement it, still looking for a better alternative.