# Auth0 Angular - Cannot match any route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, auth0

I have an angular application in which I'm trying to integrate with Auth0. I followed these two tutorials:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/02-calling-an-api

Here is the setup of my project:

**AuthService**

Copy+Pasted from the first tutorial link

**LoginController**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.authService.login();
  }
}
```

**App-Routing Module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, resolve: { queues: ProfileResolver}, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I'm getting logged in successfully, however when auth0 does its callback, it navigates to http://localhost:4200/profile?code=[code]&state=[state], which then Angular throws "Cannot match any routes".

My questions are:

1. What are the code and state parameters used for?
2. What should I do to properly handle these so my site can route to /profile properly?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: code parameter is retuned because the application is executing Authorization code flow. state parameter is used to mitigate CSRF attack. https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state

Answer (score 0):

This is a nasty gotcha with `auth0-spa-js` that caused a big headache for me in production. The issue is describe in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182111/angular-encodes-hash-fragment-how-to-prevent-it/49183582). How I solved it was changing the last line of the `handleAuthCallback` function in the auth service from:

`this.router.navigate([targetRoute])`

to:

`this.router.navigate([name-of-path-you're-redirecting-to])`.