# router navigate encodes to %3d in address bar angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to reload the current route in Angular5+ version when the click event is triggered. The following code i tried it worked but it will change the url in the address bar.

```
 this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);
```

Comment: location.reload();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 disable url encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `.reload();`

```
 window.location.reload();
```

or

```
location.reload();
```