# Angular template rendering non-encoded URL

Tags: angular5, angular2-routing, url-encoding, angular-template

How do I render a URL which is not encoded. Below is a sample

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  template: `<a [routerLink]="stringURL">Click here</a>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  stringURL:string;

  constructor(){
    this.stringURL = "/url;mode=3"
  }
}
```

The URL in the template has encoded string like `/url%3Bmode%3D3` and I want it like `/url;mode=3`

How can I achieve this.

Here's the sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q6mf3p

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the link is static, you can use the directive as follows: link to user component

If you use dynamic values to generate the link, you can pass an array of path segments, followed by the params for each segment.

For instance ['/url',{mode: 3}] means that we want to generate a link to /url;mode=3.

you code will work see this new link [click to see](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krdsde)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  template: `<a [routerLink]="stringURL">Click here</a>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  stringURL:any;

  constructor(){
    this.stringURL = ["/url",{mode:3}]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to disable angular default URL encoding.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding/41995695#41995695) explains the solution quite well.