# routerLink is rendering %23, instead of #

Tags: angular

I am trying to send href="#", using routerLink, but it is rendering  %23 instead of #.

Not sure what is wrong.

```
<a routerLink={{item.url}}>item.linkname</a>

item = {
  url: '#',
  linkname:'abcd'
}
```

Comment: What is your intention? Want to route to home? Than you can use '/'
<a [routerLink]=['/']>item.linkname</a>

Comment: lets say I just want # in routerLink, is it not possible using routerLink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular will always encode your URL with encodeURIComponent(). I do not understand what your intention is from a developer prespective but you can either:

- [Create a custom serializer to stop angular from encoding your URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding);

- If you only want to "add" an hashtag to your route you can simply use `href` instead of router link: `<a [href]="item.url">{{ item.linkname }}</a>`.